# Remove items from GridView in Flutter dynamically

Tags: gridview, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have created a grid view using GridView.count() in flutter.

Now for example at starting I have 8 items in my grid view (Maximum = 8). I want to remove particular cells from the grid based on some condition that the user will choose later. 
I'm having trouble achieving this as if I replace the grid cell with an empty container (dynamically on condition check) it still takes place in the grid while I want that cell to be completely removed (don't even take place in the GridView).
Is there a way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

Here's the code. The condition check is in the return statement on line no. 10.

```
Expanded(
                    child: GridView.count(
                      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      childAspectRatio: 0.7,
                      children: new List<Widget>.generate(
                          category != null ? category.category.length : 0,
                          (index) {
                        return _lowerLimit < category.category.elementAt(index).price && _upperLimit > caregory.categoty.elementAt(index).price ? 
                        GridTile(
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                                padding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: Hero(
                                  tag: category.category
                                      .elementAt(index)
                                      .productId,
                                  child: Material(
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.of(context).push(
                                            CupertinoPageRoute(
                                                builder: (context) =>
                                                    ItemDetails(
                                                      category.category
                                                          .elementAt(index)
                                                          .productId,
                                                      category.category
                                                          .elementAt(index)
                                                          .name,
                                                      category.category
                                                          .elementAt(index)
                                                          .description,
                                                      category.category
                                                          .elementAt(index)
                                                          .image,
                                                    )));
                                      },
                                      child: Stack(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Center(
                                            child: Image(
                                              image: _loadImage(index),
                                              height: 162.0,
                                              width: 200.0,
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Container(
                                          width: 120.0,
                                          child: Hero(
                                            tag: category.category
                                                .elementAt(index)
                                                .name,
                                            child: Text(
                                              category.category
                                                  .elementAt(index)
                                                  .name,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 12.5,
                                                  fontWeight:
                                                      FontWeight.bold),
                                              overflow:
                                                  TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          margin:
                                              EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          height: 2.0,
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          AppConstants.CURRENCY_SYMBOL +
                                              " " +
                                              double
                                                  .tryParse(category
                                                      .category
                                                      .elementAt(index)
                                                      .price)
                                                  .toStringAsFixed(2),
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 14.0,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              color: Colors.blue),
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.favorite,
                                      color: Colors.blue,
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                              Divider(
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                indent: 10.0,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ) : Container();
                      }),
                    ),
                  )
```

Comment: Please put your example here.

Comment: I've added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have a `list` *(which contains that 8 items)* by which you rendered the `GridView`.

```
new GridView.count(children: maptoWidgets(list))
```

On user actions, update the `list` within `setState` which will re-rendered the GridView with updated items.

```
setState(() {
  // update the list
})
```

**Updated based on code**:
You are having a condition like

```
_lowerLimit < category.category.elementAt(index).price && 
_upperLimit > caregory.categoty.elementAt(index).price ? GridTile() : Container()
```

Because of which if the condition is not met, we are placing an empty container. So we will get an empty space there instead of skipping that element.

**How to avoid that:**

Using filters like below

```
filteredCategory = category.category
                     .where((oneCategory) {_lowerLimit < oneCategory.price 
                                     && _upperLimit > oneCategory.price;}).toList()
```

Inside your `GridView.count` replace all category.category into filteredCategory. And user action(or when you want to refresh) simply call `setState((){})`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!. In my case I dont want to remove any item from the list (As i want the whole list for other purpose) and i want only particular items to be shown in the grid on some condition check. 
I did the condition check inside the Grid.count(). Now if the condition is matched, it is showing me the correct cell but when the condition is not matching, it is still occupying a blank space in the grid. That seems kind of strange to me. lets say i want to show 5 items (acc to condition check) but the grid is still occupying the space equal to the List size,

Comment: Can you please post the `Grid.count()` code. I would like to see how you are filtering based on condition.

Comment: Seems like we eventually need to create a second list which I was trying to avoid at the first place. But i guess it's the only way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

something as simple as this should do.

```
    //filtering the content based on user online status
    contact = contact.where((contact) => contact.onlineStatus == i).toList();
    //where i is 1 or 0, or both (using data manipulation techniques)
```